# WHy an error is generated when tuning n_estimators for RandomForestClassifier using cross_val_score?

Tags: python, cross-validation, data-science

I am working on an unbalanced data, using undersampling, I have made the both classes in the same proportion.

```
X_undersample dataframe (984,28)
y_undersample dataframe(984,1)
```

I am using randomforest classifier, in order to find the best parameter `n_estimators` I am using cross-validation. here is the code below.

```
j_shout=range(1,300)
j_acc=[]
for j in j_shout: 
   lr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = j, criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 0)
   score=cross_val_score(lr,X_undersample,y_undersample,cv=10,scoring='accuracy')
   print ('iteration',j,':cross_validation accuracy=',score)
   j_acc.append(score.mean())
```

now when I run this I am getting the following error.

```
File "<ipython-input-43-954a9717dcea>", line 5, in <module>
    score=cross_val_score(lr,X_undersample,y_undersample,cv=10,scoring='accuracy')

  File "D:\installations\AC\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1562, in cross_val_score
    cv = check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))

  File "D:\installations\AC\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1823, in check_cv
    cv = StratifiedKFold(y, cv)

  File "D:\installations\AC\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 569, in __init__
    label_test_folds = test_folds[y == label]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I try changing the `n_estimators` to smaller values but it still showing the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your traceback and scikit-learn documentation of [StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html) iterator it seems, that StratifiedKFold get y as flattened array. In your case, you pass dataframe with size (984, 1). Your part of code should be like this:

```
score=cross_val_score(estimator=lr,
                      X=X_undersample.values,
                      y=y_undersample.values.ravel(),
                      cv=10,
                      scoring='accuracy')
```